# How to get tracking id in USPS shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9

I have integrated USPS in my website and able to order with this method successfully. Order is visible in admin part but I did not get any tracking id with this order to track USPS shipping.

Can you please help me out to get tracking id.

Answer (score 0):

you can get tracking number..

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(100000064);
    $shipmentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
                ->setOrderFilter($order)
            ->load();
            foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment){
                // This will give me the shipment IncrementId, but not the actual tracking information.
                foreach($shipment->getAllTracks() as $tracknum)
                {
                    $tracknums[]=$tracknum->getNumber();
                }

            }
```